# Pre-compute Java Type Hierarchy in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class-hierarchy

Is there a way to have Eclipse pre-compute Java type hierarchies? I'm viewing an enormous project and hierarchies often take a long time to load. The project isn't mine, so organizational changes are not an option.

Thank you

Comment: At which point do you want to "pre-compute" them? When selecting a project and pressing F4, it should compute and display the whole hierarchy....

Comment: It can take two or three minutes to compute the hierarchy when I use "F4" or something similar. I'd like to have Eclipse pre-compute hierarchies before then; presumably as some kind of batch job.